# AWS-TLSv1.2 issue with the application hosted in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tls1.2

I am updating the TLS version to v1.2 in the database cluster parameter group. But upon updating it, the application that was hosted in the AWS is now erroring, when im logging in with the application, it proceeds until authentication then it seems to redirect back to the login page.

When the TLS version was set to default, I'm not encountering this issue. But I need to update the TLS version to v1.2.

Someone encountered the same kind of issue?

I tried with the default and 1.2 version of TLS and found out that the v1.2 was the source of the issue. I need to update the version of TLS to v1.2